# Google Analytics User Explorer is always empty

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to set up User-ID tracking so that my User Explorer can show user ids instead of anonymous ids.  I followed the instructions here:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en

When I go to my User ID View, the real time reports always shows zero, and my Behaviour>User Explorer always says there's no data.  Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Here's a simple web page I made on https://startmission.com/test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
<head>

  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-5315469-12"></script>
  <script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-5315469-12');
  gtag('set', {'user_id': 'sessuid-2'});
/*
  setTimeout(function(){
  gtag('set', {'user_id': 'sessuid-2'});
  gtag('set', {'userId': 'sessuid-2'});
  ga('set', 'user_id', 'sessuid-2');
  ga('set', 'userId', 'sessuid-2');
  },1000);
*/
  </script>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In Google Analytics, these are my settings:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Even when I try to uncomment the `setTimeout` in my code, my User ID View still doesn't report any results.  It's been almost 24 hours, and still no results.

---

**Other Notes**
If I go back to the "default" view, then I will get results:
[image]

---

**Update**

I got things working on another website, but I used this GA code:

```
<!-- BEGIN ExactMetrics v5.3.5 Universal Analytics - https://exactmetrics.com/ -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-102411872-1', 'auto');
  ga('set', 'userId', 'sessu-2');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Why does it work with the old GA code and not the new style `gtag.js` GA code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code worked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
<head>

  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-5315469-12"></script>
  <script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('set', {'user_id': 'sessuid-2'});
  gtag('config', 'UA-5315469-12');

  </script>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The solution was to fire the `gtag('set',{'user_id':'sessuid-2'});` before the `gtag('config', 'UA-5315469-12');`.  The `gtag('config',...)` does the actual HTTP request to google servers.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like at the moment you are hardcoding just one user ('sessuid-2'). To see data in the reports of a user id **only** view, I'd recommend trying to dynamically set the user ids and ask other people to visit the page. At the moment one user may not be enough for data to show up, theres also data processing delays so the report will not populate automatically.

In terms fo dynamically generating the user ids, this is usually set up for gated content where a user needs to log into his/her account. When a user logs in, you can grab the id that is set in the site or from your CRM tool, etc, and either save it in a cookie to later be read with Google Tag Manager, or you can also push an event to the layer that you can also later use GTM to grab the value and sent it to Google Analytics.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks is the data processing delay greater than 48 hours?  The user id is dynamically set for the pages that require you to login.  I still funny see any results in the User ID View

Comment: Hi John, sorry for the delay. Up to 24hr, no more than that.

Comment: Thanks Rafael, I just updated teh question showing that I got things working using the `old style ga` code.  So the question is why doesn't it work for the new style `gtag.js` code?